# Is it possible to upload multiple files in one request?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to upload multiple files (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multipart) by sending one request.
If for example I assembled an array that would contain a "Metadata part" for each file. And the same with the "Media part" for each file.
And then sent them in one request. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible for media files. As per the Google Drive API v3 Documentation:*

> *Note: Currently, Google Drive does not support batch operations for media, either for upload or download.*

*It is however possible to do this for regular non-media requests as per my first answer:*

#### Method:

The Google Drive API v3 has a way of sending multiple requests in one go by using a batch request. As per the batch request documentation:

> A batch request is a single standard HTTP request containing multiple Drive API calls, using the multipart/mixed content type. Within that main HTTP request, each of the parts contains a nested HTTP request.

Google has example batch requests which you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#batch-example-request), with code examples for their supported client libraries [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#using-client-libraries).

#### References:

- [Google Drive API v3 Batch Request Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)
- [Format of a batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#format-of-a-batch-request)
- [Example Batch Request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#batch-example-request)
- [Using Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#using-client-libraries)